# How do I determine the width and height of an image in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Assume I have declared my image in my pubspec.yaml like this:

```
  assets:
    - assets/kitten.jpg
```

And my Flutter code is this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    new Center(
      child: new Image.asset('assets/kitten.jpg'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Now that I have a `new Image.asset()`, how do I determine the width and height of that image? For example, I just want to print out the image's width and height.

(It looks like [dart:ui's Image class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) has width and height, but not sure how to go from widget's Image to dart:ui's Image.)

Thanks!

Comment: @quertzguy https://stackoverflow.com/a/55428773/12565404
you solution works perfect :)
thanks

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### UPDATED SOLUTION:

With the new version of flutter old solution is obsolete. Now the `addListener` needs an `ImageStreamListener`.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Image image = Image.network('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkd0a.png');
    Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
    image.image
      .resolve(ImageConfiguration())
      .addListener(
          ImageStreamListener(
              (ImageInfo info, bool _) => completer.complete(info.image)));
    ...
    ...
```

---

### ORIGINAL VERSION:

If you already have an `Image` widget, you can read the `ImageStream` out of it by calling `resolve` on its `ImageProvider`.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Image image = new Image.network('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkd0a.png');
    Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer<ui.Image>();
    image.image
      .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
      .addListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) => completer.complete(info.image));
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Image Dimensions Example"),
      ),
      body: new ListView(
        children: [
          new FutureBuilder<ui.Image>(
            future: completer.future,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ui.Image> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return new Text(
                  '${snapshot.data.width}x${snapshot.data.height}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display3,
                );
              } else {
                return new Text('Loading...');
              }
            },
          ),
          image,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: we need to update this answer. The addListener needs an ImageStreamListener. 
Even with that I get an error at this line `completer.complete(info.image)`  saying `The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<Image>`

Comment: If offline, how to calculate the size?

Comment: Will this cause the image be loaded ***twice***, thus waste a lot of network and cpu?

Comment: Needs to be:
`image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
        ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool synchronousCall) {
      completer.complete(info.image);
    }));`

Comment: @lonel Lupu
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
Completer<ui.Image>... use ui.Image as generic type.

Answer (score 121):

The other answers seem overly complicated if you just want the width and height of an image in an async function. You can get the image resolution using flutter lib directly like this:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui';

File image = new File('image.png'); // Or any other way to get a File instance.
var decodedImage = await decodeImageFromList(image.readAsBytesSync());
print(decodedImage.width);
print(decodedImage.height);
```

Comment: Looks like it's in the UI lib - import 'dart:ui';

Comment: @ajplumlee33 I didn't have to import it in my code. But maybe it's imported from another import? Are imports transcient in dart?

Comment: This returns a lot more height than the actual height of image. When I use this value to set height I get a lot of extra space at top and bottom.

Comment: @sakina: open the image in an image editor to check the height and compare it with what this function returns. It should be the same. The issue might be in the layout you are using.

Comment: @qwertzguy I think its related to scaling of the image, i.e conversion from actual resolution to logical pixels. Because if I give the height returned by the above function to the image there is a lot of empty space, but if no height is given it renders properly. Any idea how to determine this scale?

Comment: @sakina what size did you see when you opened the image in an image editor?

Comment: simplest solution and still works fine as of July 26 2020

Comment: I don't understand this part. I have an image in my assets folder and it says it can't read the image. `File image = new File("lib/pages/assets/images/road_map.png");`

Comment: hi! how do i supply a File path if the image is in assets? @qwertzguy

Comment: @nrion I think you can use rootBundle.load('assets/image.png') and pass that directly to decodeImageFromList

Comment: @qwertzguy It's not possible to pass it directly since decodeImageFromList does not accept `ByteData`. You need to convert it to `asUint8List` first: `decodeImageFromList(imgByteData.buffer.asUint8List())`

Comment: load the image from bundle:  final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('image.png');
    var decodedImage = await decodeImageFromList(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());

Answer (score 31):

Create a method, like:

```
Future<Size> _calculateImageDimension() {
  Completer<Size> completer = Completer();
  Image image = Image.network("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkd0a.png");
  image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
    ImageStreamListener(
      (ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
        var myImage = image.image;
        Size size = Size(myImage.width.toDouble(), myImage.height.toDouble());
        completer.complete(size);
      },
    ),
  );
  return completer.future;
}
```

And use it like:

```
_calculateImageDimension().then((size) => print("size = ${size}")); // 487.0,696.0
```

Comment: NOTE: when you use this code, it is not possible to save the image -- image.writeAsBytes(result) fail quietly

Comment: If offline, how to calculate?

Comment: Use `Image.file(your_file)` if you have a `File`.

Answer (score 22):

You can [`resolve`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/ImageProvider/resolve.html) the [`ImageProvider`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/ImageProvider-class.html) to get an [`ImageStream`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/ImageStream-class.html), then use [`addListener`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/ImageStream/addListener.html) to be notified when the image is ready.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  Future<ui.Image> _getImage() {
    Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer<ui.Image>();
    new NetworkImage('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkd0a.png')
      .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
      .addListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) => completer.complete(info.image));
    return completer.future;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Image Dimensions Example"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new FutureBuilder<ui.Image>(
          future: _getImage(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ui.Image> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              ui.Image image = snapshot.data;
              return new Text(
                '${image.width}x${image.height}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4);
            } else {
              return new Text('Loading...');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So basically I can't use image widget if I want to know wishes and height?

Comment: I didn't say that! I'll add another answer to show another way.

Comment: Does this fully decompress the image, or does it just read the image metadata from the stream?

Answer (score 10):

With new version of flutter old solution not working example:

```
  image.image
  .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
  .addListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) => completer.complete(info.image));
```

**Below the Working version**:

```
_image.image
    .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
    .addListener(new ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo image, bool _) {
  completer.complete(image.image);
}));
```

Comment: I can confirm this is the new way of adding a listener, but I get an error on `completer.complete(image.image);` : `The argument of type Image can't be assigned to the type parameter FutureOr<Image>`. How can this solved?

Answer (score 10):

A way for who only want decode image bounds:

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

final buffer = await ui.ImmutableBuffer.fromUint8List(bytes);
final descriptor = await ui.ImageDescriptor.encoded(buffer);

final imageWidth = descriptor.width;
final imageHeight = descriptor.height;
print("imageWidth: $imageWidth, imageHeight: $imageHeight");

descriptor.dispose();
buffer.dispose();
```

Comment: Where do you get the "bytes" from? It really helps soooooo much if you just write these things. It takes so much time to have to guess.

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård `bytes` is the byte data of the image. For example, you can get the bytes by `File('you_image_path').readAsBytesSync()` from a image file.

Comment: Thanks, but please edit your answer to contain complete sets of code!

Comment: @Summerly thanks, its very faster than `decodeImageFromList` i test with this method and `decodeImageFromList` , this method 5x faster

Comment: As of 2023, the decodeImageFromList() solution now returns void and accepts a callback, where this solution will more intuitively return a descriptor with width and height.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I don't want to decode the image before knowing the bounds. This is so that I can read the image aspect ratio and dimensions, and then decode a scaled-down version of the image with a maximum `cacheWidth` and `cacheHeight` to save RAM. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to use FutureBuilder or then, you can also use await like this:

Don't forget to import the Image. But as there are two Image classes, import it like this and use with ui.Image

```
 import 'dart:ui' as ui
```

Then you can fetch the dimensions of the image as follows.

```
 final Image image = Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/someimage.png'));
 Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer<ui.Image>();
    image.image
        .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener(new ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo image, bool _) {
      completer.complete(image.image);
    }));
 ui.Image info = await completer.future;
 int width = info.width;
 int height = info.height;
```

Comment: definitely better than the accepted answer

Comment: If you're starting with an `Image`, then why not just call `Image.width` and `Image.height`?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a handy helper function, based on other solutions

*helper function*

```dart
Future<ImageInfo> getImageInfo(Image img) async {
  final c = new Completer<ImageInfo>();
  img.image
    .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())        
    .addListener(new ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo i, bool _) {
      c.complete(i);
    }));
  return c.future;    
}
```

*usage*

```
Image image = Image.network("https://example.com/pic.png");
ImageInfo info = await getImageInfo(image);
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way how to check image dimensions that is loaded from assets.

```
var img = await rootBundle.load("Your image path");
var decodedImage = await decodeImageFromList(img.buffer.asUint8List());
int imgWidth = decodedImage.width;
int imgHeight = decodedImage.height;
```

Comment: `await` can be used in `async` functions, so may you describe how dose this code will work? Or sample code to use it.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers on this page currently only get the **raw** image size: that is the pixel height and width of the **original** image. Not the size of the image on the Flutter app. I needed that to resize bounding boxes as the page was resized. I need the current image size, and also know when it changes so I can resize the bounding box.

[image: GIF of app being resized with image and bounding box overlay resizing]

My solution involves:

- `GlobalKey` and `addPostFrameCallback` to get the image size
- Some logic to render when the image size changes

At the top of my `build` method:

```dart
  final _imageKey = GlobalKey();
  Size imageSize = Size.zero;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQuery.of(context); // Trigger rebuild when window is resized. This updates the bounding box sizes.
    final image = Image.asset(exampleImagePath, key: _imageKey);
    // Yes, we call this every time the widget rebuilds, so we update our understanding of the image size.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_updateImageSize);
```

### My `_updateImageSize`

```dart
  void _updateImageSize(Duration _) {
    final size = _imageKey.currentContext?.size;
    if (size == null) return;
    if (imageSize != size) {
      imageSize = size;
      // When the window is resized using keyboard shortcuts (e.g. Rectangle.app),
      // The widget won't rebuild AFTER this callback. Therefore, the new
      // image size is not used to update the bounding box drawing. 
      // So we call setState
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer according to the question. It works brillant in my project!

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to get asset images size.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; 

          Future<Size> _loadAssetImageSize(String asset) async{
             ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(asset);
             ui.Codec codec = await 
             ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
             ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
             return Size(fi.image.width.toDouble(), fi.image.height.toDouble());
      }
```

Comment: And where do you get this "ui" from? It helps sooooo much if you just write these things... rather than forcing us to find the info elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

This code loads an image asset asynchronously and obtains its width and height.
This code loads an image asset named "my_image.png" from the "assets" directory using the Image.asset() method.

A Completer object is created to handle the asynchronous loading of the image. The Completer is used to complete the future when the image is loaded.

An ImageStreamListener is added to the image's image stream using the addListener() method. The ImageStreamListener is triggered when the image is fully loaded and provides an ImageInfo object containing information about the loaded image. The Completer is then completed with the loaded ui.Image object.

Finally, the future from the Completer is awaited to get the ui.Image object. The width and height of the ui.Image object are then obtained using the width and height properties respectively.

```
Image image = Image.asset('assets/my_image.png');
Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(  
ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
    completer.complete(info.image); 
 }), 
);
ui.Image myImage = await completer.future; 
int width = myImage.width;
int height = myImage.height;
```

Comment: I fixed your formatting. Please give more details on how this answers the question.