# What is the correct way to instantiate ImageShader?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need an ImageShader for my custom painter. Constructor requires Image.

I've tried to get AssetImage but I don't see the way to transform it into Image directly.

Now I'm stuck on decodeImageFromList(). How can I transform AssetImage into Uint8List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapted from my answer on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665955/how-do-i-determine-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-flutter), here is how to turn an `AssetImage` into a `ui.Image`.

```
  Future<ui.Image> _getImage() {
    Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer<ui.Image>();
    new AssetImage('assets/image.png')
      .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
      .addListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) => completer.complete(info.image));
    return completer.future;
  }
```