# What do I pass to the Flutter Completer object?

Tags: image, dart, flutter, size, future

A previous question on stack overflow discussed obtaining an image's size to which someone posted an answer

```
    Future<ui.Image> _getImage() {
        Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer<ui.Image>();
        new NetworkImage('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkd0a.png')
          .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
          .addListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) => completer.complete(info.image));
        return completer.future;
  }
```

Unfortunately the above code will not compile due to `complete.complete(info.image)` having an error in Android Studio which says:

> the argument type 'image' can't be assigned to the parameter type
>   'FutureOr'

Could someone suggest how to correct the code so that the Completer object will work properly?

I would ask the original poster of the accepted answer but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.  So I am asking the question here.

The link to the original post is here:

[How do I determine the width and height of an image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665955/how-do-i-determine-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the types do not match up.

Looking at your code, it should work since `ImageInfo.image` should return `ui.Image`.

First of all, you can omit the type in the constructor, like this:

```
Completer<Image> completer = Completer();
```

If you are still having issues, it would be helpful to see more of the stack trace.