# How to define height and width to an image inside Flutter Markdown?

Tags: flutter, markdown

I want to use custom height and width of image inside Flutter Markdown String.
How can I do that?

```
    String markdownString = """
  You can include images:

![Flutter logo](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSobAPMeqgsRtHrX8vclVHPggkhqcSt0q1ixhyokNq3Wa16TGF6Mp34Cjo)
""";
```

In my case it is showing the actual size of the image, But I want to give it custom height and weight.

Comment: Perhaps the answers to this question could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665955/how-do-i-determine-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-flutter

Comment: As explained in the following link, markdown would support the ability to specify the size of the image. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/changing-image-size-in-markdown

Unfortunatly flutter_markdown does not support this.

What I'm considering to do is put the image in a table, which allows to resize to some degree, but it's obviously not ideal / what we need.

Answer (score 6):

you can use **#50x50** mean #width x height

```
![Flutter logo](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSobAPMeqgsRtHrX8vclVHPggkhqcSt0q1ixhyokNq3Wa16TGF6Mp34Cjo#50x50)
```