# How to determine width and height of a cached network image?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to get the height of a CachedNetworkImage. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665955/how-do-i-determine-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-flutter) solution to get the height of a regular network image. Is there a way to implement this for a cached image?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just a little modification from this existing solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57640169/5882307 worked.

**Code:**

```
  Future<Size> _calculateImageDimension() {
  Completer<Size> completer = Completer();
  Image image = new Image(image: CachedNetworkImageProvider("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkd0a.png")); // I modified this line
  image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
    ImageStreamListener(
      (ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
        var myImage = image.image;
        Size size = Size(myImage.width.toDouble(), myImage.height.toDouble());
        completer.complete(size);
      },
    ),
  );
  return completer.future;
}
```

**Use as:**

```
_calculateImageDimension().then((size) => print("size = ${size}")); // 487.0,696.0
```

*All due credits to the original author: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57640169/5882307*

Comment: can you explain what modification you made ? looks exactly same

Comment: It's already commented out in the code that I added. Care to read. I have used cached network image provider instead of Image.networl() widget

Comment: thanks for clarifying. your inline code comment not visible without scrolling.