# How to get size of the drawn image in actual logical pixels?

Tags: flutter, dart, pixel

I would like to know how to get the size of the drawn image in logical pixels. [I know how to get image size in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665955/how-do-i-determine-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-flutter), and I could convert that to logical pixels, but the problem is that those are not the actual pixels of the image drawn on the screen. I would like to know how to get how much logical pixels of the display do the image occupy when drawn on the screen.

Comment: *"I would like to know how to get the size of the drawn image"* - how do you draw that image?

Comment: @pskink I draw it with Image.asset('assets/image.png')