# How to get the size of a network image in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need to get the file size of the image that is a network image. I mean size in Kb, Mb, etc. How can I get it?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665955/how-do-i-determine-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-flutter

Answer (score 3):

You can get the size of the network Image by HTTP head request.

```
  http.Response r = await http.head(Uri.parse('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkd0a.png'));
  print(r.headers["content-length"]); //545621 means 546 KB
```