# How to set a widget dimensions as the same than other? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to set a widget dimensions as the same than other, i have an image widget that is displayed in the screen, and need to use ClipRRect to set the dimensions of an custom drawing canvas to make impossible draw out of the image.

My current code:

```
class DrawingCanvas extends HookWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<Color> selectedColor;
  final ValueNotifier<double> strokeSize;
  final ValueNotifier<double> eraserSize;
  final ValueNotifier<DrawingMode> drawingMode;
  final AnimationController sideBarController;
  final ValueNotifier<Sketch?> currentSketch;
  final ValueNotifier<List<Sketch>> allSketches;
  final GlobalKey canvasGlobalKey;
  final ValueNotifier<bool> filled;
  final String imagePath;
  final double? imageHeight;
  final double? imageWidth;

  const DrawingCanvas({
    Key? key,
    required this.selectedColor,
    required this.strokeSize,
    required this.eraserSize,
    required this.drawingMode,
    required this.sideBarController,
    required this.currentSketch,
    required this.allSketches,
    required this.canvasGlobalKey,
    required this.filled,
    required this.imagePath,
    this.imageWidth,
    this.imageHeight,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Image.file(
          File(imagePath),
        ),
        LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                    height: constraints.maxHeight,
                    child: buildAllPaths(),
                  ),
                ),
                ClipRRect(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: constraints.maxWidth, // here is the problem. Constraints maxwidth is the width of the screen...
                    height: constraints.maxHeight,
                    child: buildCurrentPath(context),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget buildAllPaths() {
    return RepaintBoundary(
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: SketchPainter(sketches: allSketches.value),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildCurrentPath(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerDown: (details) {
        final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
        final offset = box.globalToLocal(details.position);

        currentSketch.value = Sketch.fromDrawingMode(
          Sketch(
            points: [offset],
            color: selectedColor.value,
            size: strokeSize.value,
          ),
          drawingMode.value,
          filled.value,
        );
      },
      onPointerMove: (details) {
        final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
        final offset = box.globalToLocal(details.position);
        final points = List<Offset>.from(currentSketch.value?.points ?? [])
          ..add(offset);

        currentSketch.value = Sketch.fromDrawingMode(
            Sketch(
                points: points,
                color: selectedColor.value,
                size: strokeSize.value),
            drawingMode.value,
            filled.value);
      },
      onPointerUp: (details) {
        allSketches.value = List<Sketch>.from(allSketches.value)
          ..add(currentSketch.value!);
      },
      child: RepaintBoundary(
        child: SizedBox(
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: SketchPainter(
                sketches:
                    currentSketch.value == null ? [] : [currentSketch.value!]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Basicaly, i need to build buildCurrentPath and buildAllPaths in the same dimensions of the image file! But the image is sended by the user and i dont know the dimensions!

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

[how-do-i-determine-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665955/how-do-i-determine-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-flutter)

You can get the dimension of the image and update the widget size accordingly

Comment: Yes, thanks for it! <3

Comment: I need to try the implementation yet, i read but dont finish the code.